# Mi codigo no verifica si el numero que ingreso se esta repitiendo

Tags: c

Mi archivo cuando ingreso el codigo (primer int de la estructura), no me verifica si se esta repitiendo el numero con la funcion repetir . En este codigo solo deje las funciones que no me funcionaban , entonces si hay llamadas a funciones que no aparecen es por esto .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 2
#define STR 20

typedef struct{
    int codigo;
    char nombre[STR];
    int edad;
    bool prendido;    
}usuario;
  
int main(){
    menu();
    return 0;
}


void menu(){        
    FILE *f ;   
    listar(f);
    ordenar(f);     
    return;
}

//funcion para listar la info del archivo
void listar(FILE *f){       
    f = fopen("minera.txt","a"); 
    usuario usuario1;
    int codigos[MAX],num;
   fprintf(f,"Codigo \t Nombre \t Edad \t Estado \n");
```

Aca hago el procedimiento para ingresar el codigo

```
   //ciclo para ingresar los datos
   for(int i =0;i<MAX;i++){
   printf("Ingrese el codigo de 4 digitos de su cuenta \n");
   codigos[i] = val_codigo(); 
   //funcion para ver si repite el numero
   while (repetido(num,i,codigos)){
    printf("Numero repetido, ingrese otro \n");
    codigos[i]=val_codigo();
   }
   codigos[i]=num;
   usuario1.codigo = codigos[i];
  
   }    
   }
fclose(f);
    return;
}
```

Esta es la funcion que me estaria dando problemas

```
bool repetido (int n1,int n2,int arreglo[]){
    for(int i =0;i<n2;i++){
        if(n1==arreglo[i])return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿qué tiene asignado `num`? ¿qué hace `val_codigo()`? si compartes un poco más de código quizás podamos ayudarte mejor. No compartas únicamente lo que no te funciona, acláralo, está bien, pero siempre es mejor un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hola tomas, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 2):

```
bool Repetido (int n1,int n2,int arreglo[])
{
    bool duplicado = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        if (n1 == arreglo[i])
        {
           duplicado = true;
           break;
        }
        
        return duplicado;
    }
}
```

La **función Repetido** debes hacerla de la siguiente forma:

Declaras la **variable local duplicado** y la inicializas en **false**, posteriormente ejecutas un **ciclo for** que recorrerá todos los elementos del arreglo y cuando se cumpla la condición **n1 == arreglo[i]** entonces la **variable duplicado** tomará el valor **true** y se saldrá del **ciclo for** a través de la instrucción **break**. Por último se retorna el valor que tiene la **variable duplicado**.

De no cumplirse nunca la condición **n1 == arreglo[i]** entonces la **variable duplicado** siempre será **false**.

Tu **función Repetido** no funcionaba porque no recorrías todo el arreglo completo ya que en la condición **n1 == arreglo[i]** sea cual fuese el valor que esta condición retornara hacías un **return** saliendo inmediatamente de la función.